# Nesting Queries to get multiple column results

Tags: sql

Have two queries , one collects moves in based on property and unit type the other would collect based on Move Outs for the same data. when ran separately they yield the correct information (move outs are 6 and move ins are 11) Have tried nesting in select and from statements but not getting what i need. When nested within the select am getting the correct move outs per unit type, but each line for move ins is total move ins. I recall that the nesting here would only return one value but know there is a way to return the value for each row. Any assistance is appreciated.

```
SELECT 
    p.scode as PropNumber,
    p.saddr1 propname,
    ut.scode as UnitType, 
    COUNT(t.hmyperson) as Moveouts, 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(t.hmyperson) as MoveIns
        FROM 
            tenant t
            JOIN unit u      ON t.hunit = u.hmy
            JOIN property p  ON p.hmy   = u.hproperty
            JOIN unittype ut ON ut.hmy  = u.HUNITTYPE
        WHERE 
            t.dtmovein >= getdate() - 14
            AND p.scode IN ('gsaff')
    ) mi
FROM 
    Property p  
    JOIN unit u ON u.hproperty = p.hmy
    JOIN tenant t ON t.hunit = u.hmy
    JOIN unittype ut ON ut.hmy = u.HUNITTYPE 
WHERE 
    p.scode IN ('gsaff') 
    AND  t.DTMOVEOUT >= getdate()- 14 
GROUP BY 
    ut.scode,
    p.scode,
    p.saddr1
```

With this data is coming out like :

```
PropNumber       Propname       UnitType    MoveOuts     MoveIns
```

`1               x             tc2          1           11
1               x             tc3          2           11
1               x             tc4          1           11
1               x             tc5          1           11
1               x             tc6          1           11 <pre>`

Move in column should display as
2
5
1
0
3

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of your problem and the tables you are  using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to *correlate* the subquery according to the record being processed in the outer query. This also requires that you use different table aliases in the subquery than in the outer query.

It is hard to tell without seeing sample data, however I would expect that you need to correlate with all non-aggregated columns in the outer query.

Try changing :

```
(
    SELECT COUNT(t.hmyperson) as MoveIns
    FROM 
        tenant t
        JOIN unit u      ON t.hunit = u.hmy
        JOIN property p  ON p.hmy   = u.hproperty
        JOIN unittype ut ON ut.hmy  = u.HUNITTYPE
    WHERE 
        t.dtmovein  >= getdate() - 14
        AND p.scode IN ('gsaff')
) mi
```

To :

```
(
    SELECT COUNT(t.hmyperson) as MoveIns
    FROM 
        tenant t1
        JOIN unit u1      ON t1.hunit = u1.hmy
        JOIN property p1  ON p1.hmy   = u1.hproperty
        JOIN unittype ut1 ON ut1.hmy  = u1.HUNITTYPE
    WHERE 
        t1.dtmovein   >= getdate() - 14
        AND p1.scode  IN ('gsaff')
        AND p1.scode  = p.scode
        AND p1.saddr1 = p.saddr1
        AND ut1.scode = ut.scode
) mi
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight, am getting Subquery returned more than 1  1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: @Mike "Thanks for the insight, am getting Subquery returned more than 1 1 value" Not possible `COUNT(*)` always return one record without using a `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: Raymond and GMB thanks you, the code provided is correct and the change from Count(t.hmyperson) to count(*) in that snippet worked like it is supposed to